# Gitlab syncing folder "hooks" in all repositories of group

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, gitlab, gitlab-omnibus

I have Gitlab setted locally on my server. I noticed, that when i am adding some code to "post-receive" file in some repository, all changes applying to all other repositories in that group.

How to stop it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the "[Custom Git hooks setup](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/administration/custom_hooks.html#setup)":

> Normally, Git hooks are placed in the repository or project's hooks directory. **GitLab creates a symlink from each project's hooks directory to the gitlab-shell hooks directory for ease of maintenance between gitlab-shell upgrades**.

This explains why your hook seems to be propagated to *all* repos of the group.

> Follow the steps below to set up a custom hook:
>
> - Pick a project that needs a custom Git hook.
> - On the GitLab server, navigate to the project's repository directory. For an installation from source the path is usually `/home/git/repositories/<group>/<project>.git`.
>     For Omnibus installs the path is usually `/var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories/<group>/<project>.git`.
> - **Create a new directory in this location called `custom_hooks`**.
> - Inside the new custom_hooks directory, create a file with a name matching the hook type.
>     For a `pre-receive` hook the file name should be `pre-receive` with no extension.
> - Make the hook file executable and make sure it's owned by git.
> - Write the code to make the Git hook function as expected

Comment: i have problem. Now, my hooks doesnt work. I have changed owner of folder, owner of hook, all names are actual, i have make hook executable. I am using post-receive to deploy code to folder(/etc/*destination_folder/), even grant 777 permission for folder to which i want deploy, but it doesnt work. Can you say something about this problem?

Comment: "my hooks doesnt work." Do you have an error message? Try adding some echo to your hooks to see if they are executed (and an `env` command to see with which environment variables that script is working with)

Comment: how to check it?When i use this hook as global for all projects - it was working perfectly

Comment: @lucas63 Basically, on Stack Overflow, just saying "it does not work" is not enough: what do you expect, what do you see, with which exact configuration: ask a new question with *all* those details and we can help you.